# :focus ring removal on :before pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a button with span included which then has a pseudo-selector, :before applied to it in some cases.

When the element (button) receives focus, the :before is also receiving focus and the focus ring, resulting in something like this:

[image: bad button]

While I'd like to keep the focus ring on the button itself, I'm having a difficulty removing it from the contained :before element. See this JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uhgsj6cp/3/

The HTML/CSS is fairly basic:

```css
.btn {
  width: 100px
}

.btn>span {
  position: relative;
}

.btn>span:before {
  display: block;
  content: '•';
  font-size: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -13px;
  top: -13px;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn btn-default'>
    <span>Text</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the `line-height` then hide the overflow:

```css
.btn {
  width: 100px
}

.btn>span {
  position: relative;
}

.btn>span:before {
  /*display: block; not need*/
  content: '•';
  font-size: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -13px;
  top: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  line-height:0.4;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn btn-default'>
        <span>Text</span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to ALMOST remove that artifact outline with adjusting line-height and top on the pseudo element.

However, you could also try using the HTML `&#8226;` to produce the bullet within the button.

Comment: I'd gotten to the `almost` point as well - but it was annoying. There's no impact between using the HTML entity and a UTF-8 character to generate the bullet. The design called for the bullet not offsetting the button text.